# Running process in .conf file

Tags: bash, shell, server, supervisord, systemctl

I have a simple file server_config.conf with below content

```
[program:flaskapp_server]
command=gunicorn app:app
numprocs=1
directory=/home/ubuntu/flaskapp/ 
user=ubuntu
```

And I have one more file start_server_config.sh

I want to run the program flaskapp_server in background from this bash script. How can I do that.

I saw an answer somewhere that It has be copied in some directory conf.d and supervisorctl will read it. But I want to execute and kill it from the bash script. How can I achieve that

Answer (score 0):

After lot of searching I got a solution
this command can run processes in .conf

```
supervisord -c /home/ubuntu/flaskapp/super.conf
```